# python - requests.get (Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')

Tags: python

I'm new to web scraper, tried to access a website but got too many errors and was told (Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT').

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
urla="https://www.loopnet.com/search/office-space/san-diego-ca/for-lease/?sk=02fa1ad85634ef43bfd21f24bbe3a14a"
source = requests.get(urla).text
print(source)
```

---

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
1343             try:
-> 1344                 response.begin()
1345             except ConnectionError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in begin(self)
305         while True:
--> 306             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
307             if status != CONTINUE:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
266     def _read_status(self):
--> 267         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
268         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
588             try:
--> 589                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
590             except timeout:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
317             else:
--> 318                 raise SocketError(str(e))
319         except OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError:

OSError: (60, 'ETIMEDOUT')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
450                 )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
719             retries = retries.increment(
--> 720                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
721             )

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(60, 'ETIMEDOUT')"))
(Something like this)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the server is not responding or is taking too long to respond.
you should always encapsulate the requests in a try block to avoid program crash, This way you can catch any error, or specific errors by using the requests.exceptions module

```
import requests
url="https://www.loopnet.com/search/office-space/san-diego-ca/for-lease/?sk=02fa1ad85634ef43bfd21f24bbe3a14a"
```

**Catch any error**

```
try:
    source = requests.get(url).text
except:
    print 'ERROR'
```

**Catch ConnectionError**

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    source = requests.get(url).text
except ConnectionError:                  # <-- this is your case scenario
    print 'NOT RESPONDING'
```

**Catch TimeoutError**

```
from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout

try:
    source = requests.get(url, timeout=2).text  # <-- you should always use timeout to avoid requests hanging or taking too long to respond
except ReadTimeout:
    print 'TIMEOUT'
```

**You can view all the requests exceptions like this**

```
for exception in dir(requests.exceptions):
    print exception
```

Read requests exceptions docs here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions